Total vs MaxRpc timeout
Going through Retry settings at - https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/gax/latest/com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings
I am not able to understand the difference between these two timeout settings.

getMaxRpcTimeout - MaxRpcTimeout puts a limit on the value of the RPC timeout, so that the RpcTimeoutMultiplier can't increase the RPC timeout higher than this amount.
getTotalTimeout() - TotalTimeout has ultimate control over how long the logic should keep trying the remote call until it gives up completely.

Is RPC timeout same as timeout while establishing the Connection with Firestore? or is  that part of TotalTimeout?
